# Extending available annotation feature to another custom annotation

Tags: java, web-services, spring, annotations

I am creating custom Endpoint annotation for webservice to our project framework which is similar to org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint. I just want to add some extra functionality and give the same feature as defined in spring. 

Is there any way to extend the feature of spring Endpoint annotation and add some extra finctioanlity to that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, it is possible to implement your own annotation as endpoint by overriding methods from [AbstractAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/mapping/AbstractAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.html). If you extend soap endpoint mapping, it should be possible to let it process your annotated element, so you can and modify and return its invocation chain.